# C# How to programmatically import files into Visual Studio project

Tags: c#, file, import

I have a file upload control that imports files into a directory on the server. I would like to import the file in the servers file system into my project programmatically using C#. It is an image that I would like to import so I can display that image to the website. An Alternative method maybe when I use the file upload control, to import directly into the websites folder. Can anyone help with this?

The code I have is as follows:-
Image1.ImageUrl = "~c:\users\fitzy\documents\visual studio\2013\Projects\PhotoGallery3\PhotoGallery3\photos\Appliance Insurance.JPG";

I want to be able to display the imported image using Image1.ImageUrl but the path on the server does not let me.

Comment: Please indicate `does not let me` is it an error and if so what exactly is the exception?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since we do not know the error message, I am sharing 2 mostly possible reasons:

1. Your server user identity may not have a write permission to the upload folder. Check your upload folder if a newly uploaded file is located there or not.
2. Usage of an incorrect file path for uploaded images on the server, so your website cannot find them. You can see this case by 404 error message on your browser.

Comment: I have managed to get the code to see the photos in the windows directory that it is mapped to where the server path is, even though the files do not appear in Visual Studio.

Comment: @Lardblast, maybe you can try to create a file manually on your server drive, then try to see it in your Visual Studio. In this way, you can verify if your computer has a network path to your Server folder. Otherwise, you cannot see the contents of your Server folder in the Visual Studio. Again, if you can verify those 2 items above in my answer, most probably you will find the reason.